# Jython optional code directive?

Tags: python, debugging, jython

The `-O` (capital letter O) switch hasn't been implemented in Jython, which means the `__debug__` thing doesn't work: i.e. you can't have it evaluate to True during development and False in production.

You can work around this by giving a class a "debug" attribute, for example, and then setting this to False when running code for production.  But doesn't this mean you are getting the code to evaluate the condition `if App.debug:...` all the time?

Is there a better way?

**Later:** Re the comment implying that test-driven development is that "better way".  I imply in my comment in reply to his that one does not exclude the other, and give what I think is a good reason why I think too much reliance can sometimes be placed on TDD.

But there's another reason why `__debug__` is something one might want to make use of when developing code: the BDFL has indeed implemented it for CPython!

Comment: A better way is to write tests.

Comment: What is the `-o` switch? There is no such option for [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) or [Jython](http://www.jython.org/docs/using/cmdline.html)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html --> 6.13.  Yeah, I'm a TDD fanatic.  But TDD is never foolproof. There are always going to be tests you could have written but didn't realise you had to.  I'll go further: you wouldn't be able to write a single line of code if your tests were cover any and every eventuality.

Comment: That's `-O` not `-o`. It's not optional code, it's optimised. It doesn't define `__debug__`.

Comment: eh? docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html --> 7.3. "the built-in variable \_debug_ is True under normal circumstances, False when optimization is requested (command line option -O)".